# recursive method returning original value

Tags: python, recursion

So I'm trying to learn python on my own, and am doing coding puzzles. I came across one that pretty much ask for the best position to stand in line to win a contest. The person running the contest gets rid of people standing in odd number positions.

So for example if 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

It would get rid of the odd positions leaving 2, 4

Would get rid of the remaining odd positions leaving 4 as the winner.

When I'm debugging the code seems to be working, but it's returning `[1,2,3,4,5]` instead of the expected `[4]`

Here is my code:

```
def findWinner(contestants):
    if (len(contestants) != 1):
        remainingContestants = []
        for i, contestant in enumerate(contestants, 1):
            if (isEven(i)):
                remainingContestants.append(contestant)
        findWinner(remainingContestants)
    return contestants
```

Am I not seeing a logic error or is there something else that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must return the value from the recurse function to the caller function:

```
return findWinner(remainingContestants)
```

else you would return just the original value without any changes.

```
def findWinner(contestants):
    if (len(contestants) != 1):
        remainingContestants = []
        for i, contestant in enumerate(contestants, 1):
            if (isEven(i)):
                remainingContestants.append(contestant)
        return findWinner(remainingContestants) # here the value must be return
    return contestants # without the return above, it will just return this value(original)
```

Comment: Ah, that works. Thanks, I'm not sure what you mean I'm still going to need to remove the even contestants after I remove the odd ones though? I'm getting my expected results now and I don't see anything else wrong with the logic...

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
def findWinner(contestants):
    return [contestants[2**int(math.log(len(contestants),2))-1]]
```

I know its not what the questions really about but I had to =P.  I cant just look at all that work for finding the greatest power of 2 less than contestants and not point it out.

or if you don't like the 'artificial' solution and would like to actually perform the process:

```
def findWinner2(c):  
    while len(c) > 1:  
        c = [obj for index, obj in enumerate(c, 1) if index % 2 == 0]  #or c = c[1::2] thanks desfido  
    return c
```

Comment: I tested out all the different solutions, the first method with the math is definitely the fastest, the second way you wrote is actually the second fastest with the slicing slightly behind it. I honestly don't understand the mathematics behind what you did though. The second (and alternatively, desfido's method) way of doing it I understand find, it just isn't the first thing I thought of since I just literally started learning python a day or two ago. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: slicing slower?  I wouldnt have thought. creating that enumerate unnecessarily seems like a waste, but I guess I don't know what happens behind the scenes when you slice. I'll try to explain to you the math in my first way quickly in the comment below this.

Comment: Each pass you eliminate contestants in odd position and halve the index of those in even position.  Those in a position of a higher power of 2 (2^4=16,2^5=32,etc) can be halved the most times before becoming odd.  First pass - eliminate odd positions (divisible by 2^0==1, not divisible by 2^1==2). Nth pass - eliminate contestants ORIGINALLY in positions divisible by 2^n-1 but not 2^n.  So... log base 2 of len(c) means find x where 2^x = len(c).  This is probably not integer, so get the integer right below it w/ int(x).  2^int(x) is pos of winner, but we subtract by 1 since array starts at 0.

Comment: A thought - I think you found desfido's slicing was slower bc he left the recursion in place.  If you take his slicing idea and put it into my second, like i show in the comment, it will likely be the second fastest behind the math/logarithm version.

Answer (score 1):

you shold use

```
return findWinner(remaingContestants)
```

otherwise, of course, your list will never be updated and so your func is gonna always return containts

however, see the PEP8 for style guide on python code: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

the func isEven is probably an overkill...just write

```
if not num % 2
```

finally, recursion in python isn't recommended; make something like

```
def find_winner(alist):
    while len(alist) > 1:
        to_get_rid = []
        for pos, obj in enumerate(alist, 1):
            if pos % 2:
                to_get_rid.append(obj)
        alist = [x for x in alist if not (x in to_get_rid)]
    return alist
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're iterating over the list instead of using a slice? Doesn't seem very python-y to not use them to me.

Additionally, you might want to do something sensible in the case of an empty list. You'll currently go into an infinite loop.

I'd write your function as

```
def findWinner(contestants):
    if not contestants:
        raise Exception
    if len(contestants)==1:
        return contestants[0]
    return findWinner(contestants[1::2])
```

(much as @jon_darkstar's point, this is a bit tangential to the question you are explicitly asking, but still a good practice to engage in over what you're doing)

Comment: so what?  yeah its good that they cleared up his recursion issue, but this is good to show also.  that slice is a fantastic idea, better than the list comp i did in my second example.  +1   (btw the term is pythonic!)

Comment: I figured there was an easier way of doing it, clearly I still have a lot to learn with Python! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return at the line where you call "findWinner"